# Slack Bitbucket Integration

Tags: bitbucket, slack

I get 403 errors and a hanging page when i try to set up slack integrations, any idea what causes this?

These are the URL's

GET
`bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/MyAccount/repo-name/hooks/?pagelen=100`

POST
`bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/MyAccount/repo-name/hooks/`

If anyone else knows bitbucket well there is also the option to prevent deletion of repos which when i try to enable a !Forbidden message also appears. Are these related to my account being on the free tier? There is very little error feedback.

Answer (score 17):

**edit**

From [Atlassian's Bitbucket Cloud for Slack how-to](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-for-slack-945096776.html):

(Requires repo admin permissions)

1. Log into [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.com/)
2. Open a specific repository to add notifications to, in the
   account that is connected to Slack.
3. Click **Settings** then select **Chat
   notifications > Settings**.
4. Choose one of the following:

   - Click **Add subscription**, if you've already connected this repository 
     to Slack.
   - Click the **connect** button, if this the first time your
     connecting a repository to your Slack workspace.
   - Click **Add subscription** and then select **Add new workspace**, if you’re
     adding a new subscription, to a new workspace.
5. Choose the Slack workspace and channel to connect to your repository.

**/edit**

---

Not sure how you're trying to do it, but here is how I got mine to work:

1. Make sure you have the Bitbucket app installed on Slack. It should show up on your yourteam.slack.com/apps/manage page. In case it doesn't, search Bitbucket on the [app directory](https://slack.com/apps)
2. Once in the Bitbucket app page on Slack, go to its configuration page (or create a new configuration). Decide to which channel or user should Bitbucket notifications be posted.
3. On the same page, find the Webhook URL. It looks something like https://hooks.slack.com/services/LONGST/RINGOF/RANDOMChAraCTeRS
4. On your Bitbucket repository page, click Settings/Webhooks.
5. Use the Slack URL to create a new Webhook. Assign a unique name to it. I believe Slack only supports Repository Push type of trigger.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Slack now works at least with issue items too. This makes me happy. And I suspect many more triggers are now supported okay.

Comment: For step 4, under my Bitbucket repository's Settings -> Workflow options it only shows a link for "Hooks" (not "Webhooks") and from there the "Add hook" button only allows me to search, not add one from URL. Am I missing some kind of access here?

Comment: @starmandeluxe same here.. I think that's about Bitbucket local installation version.

Comment: @ThiagoGouvea could you please specify which software to install? in slack apps repository, there are only Bitbucket Server and Bitbucket Cloud;
Also, how and where to put the configuration exactly? thanks.

Comment: It looks like things changed a little since - good news is they seem to have gotten easier. I'll edit my reply to include a link to Atlassian's how-to.

Comment: This answer should be mentioned somewhere in the Slack bitbucket app page.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-for-slack-945096776.html) you can use chat notifications instead of webhooks:

> 1. Log into Bitbucket
> 2. Open a specific repository to add notifications to, in the account that is connected to Slack.
> 3. Click **Settings** then select **Chat notifications > Settings**.
>    Choose one of the following:
>
>    1. Click **Add subscription**, if you've already connected this repository to Slack.
>    2. Click the **connect** button, if this the first time your connecting a repository to your Slack workspace.
>    3. Click **Add subscription** and then select **Add new workspace**, if you’re adding a new subscription, to a new workspace.
> 4. Choose the Slack workspace and channel to connect to your repository.
>
> ---
>
> You can subscribe to additional repositories via **Chat Notifications > Settings**, or by typing `/bitbucket connect <repository URL>` in a Slack workspace that has been previously connected to Bitbucket.